# differences in python path handling with trailing dot ('.') between linux and windows

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, cross-platform

I came across a surprising result while fixing for a cross-platform bug in a python script.
(*sidenote:* same venv specified by poetry, otoh this is basic python library functionality)

wanting to reduce some path-trunk by a header part, i used:
`os.path.relpath('../data/what/ever/path/trunk.', '../data/')`
which for **linux** yields:
`'what/ever/path/trunk.'`
while **windows** produces:
`'what/ever/path/trunk'` (mark the *missing dot* at the end)

why is this, and how can such aberrant behavior be justified ?

Comment: Normal behavior for both OS. On Windows the . merely separates the filename from the extension, on Linux it's significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, the last `.` in a filename is used to separate the file extension from the rest of the filename. If the extension is blank, the `.` is optional; both forms would reference the same file.

Linux doesn't have filename extensions, so the trailing `.` is a valid part of the filename and must be preserved.